# What are the security implications of using an iPhone purchased in China

Tags: mobile, ios, iphone

I recently bought an iPhone off Craigslist, but It's come to my attention that the phone was purchased by it's original owner in China (The model no is: A1528). Are there any security implications if I use this device? Is there a possibility of a state sponsored back door or similar?

Comment: Sure, there's the possibility. The Chinese government has been forcing people to Download apps which syphon messages and data on Android phones in certain regions of China. I haven't personally heard about the OS being compromised though. Here's a quick guide of stuff to check. It's not exactly related to your situation, but may give you more info https://www.eyes4tech.com/check-if-an-iphone-is-original-or-fake/. The Apple store may be able to re-upload the OS (just a guess, I'm an Android man myself). Best of luck

Comment: Since all iPhones are made in China, the chance of a backdoor isn’t really any higher for one that was also purchased in China than it is for any other iPhone.